# How to use the Pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, pure-css

I wanna create a 404 error webpage using the code provided here:

https://codepen.io/SofiaSergio/pen/RMjyRL

As the author mentioned, this is pure CSS. Howsoever I'm not sure if the usage of Pure CSS is same as standard CSS. I created an HTML and CSS file `mystyle.css` , placed them in a folder

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
</head>

<body>       
<div class="text"><p>503</p></div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- caveman left -->
  <div class="caveman">
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="shape">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eye"><div class="nose"></div></div>
      <div class="mouth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arm-right"><div class="club"></div></div>    
  </div>
  <!-- caveman right -->
  <div class="caveman">
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="shape">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eye"><div class="nose"></div></div>
      <div class="mouth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arm-right"><div class="club"></div></div>    
  </div>
</div>
<!-- //////////////// CREDIT //////////////// -->
<a href="https://codepen.io/SofiaSergio/" target="_blank">
  <div id="link">
    <i class="fab fa-codepen"></i>
    <p>watch other pens</p>
  </div>
</a>
</body>
 </html>
```

However, It just shows a big number with orange background. I tried to make CSS in a style tag and I had same result:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
 body { background-color: #FF7F2E; font-family: 'Concert One', cursive; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; }

/*/////////////////// rules */
$color-black:     #13242C;
$color-white:     #fff;
$color-red-1:     #D13433;
$color-red-2:     #932422;
$color-skin-1:    #EAB08C;
$color-skin-2:    #D9766C;
$color-skin-3:    #B2524D;
$color-hair:      #13242C;
$color-wood-1:    #601513;
$color-wood-2:    #410A09;

@mixin position {
  position: absolute;
}
@mixin top50 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
@mixin left50 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
@mixin centered {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*/////////////////// scene */
.text {
  @include centered;
  color: rgba($color-black, 0.1);
  font-size: 30em;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
}
.container {
  @include centered;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  &:after {
    @include position;
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba($color-black, 0.1);
    border-radius: 12px;
    bottom: 40px;
    height: 12px;
    left: 80px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
/*/////////////////// caveman */
.caveman {
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
}
.caveman:nth-child(1) { right: 20px; }
.caveman:nth-child(2) { left: 20px; transform: rotateY(180deg); }
.head {
  @include position;
  background-color: $color-hair;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 140px;
  left: 60px;
  top: 25px;
  width: 65px;
  &:after, &:before {
    content: "";
    @include position;
    background-color: $color-black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 7px;
  }
  &:after   { left: 35px; top: -8px; transform:rotate(20deg); }
  &:before  { left: 30px; top: -8px; transform:rotate(-20deg); }
  .eye {
    @include left50;
    background-color: $color-skin-1;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 45%;
    top: 40px;
    width: 48px;
    &:after, &:before {
      content: "";
      @include top50;
      background-color: $color-black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 5px;
      width: 5px;
    }
    &:after {
      left: 5px;
    }
    &:before {
      right: 9px;
    }
    .nose {
      @include centered;
      background-color: $color-skin-2;
      border-left: 8px solid rgba($color-black, 0.1);
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 35px;
      left: 45%;
      top: 12px;
      width: 15px;
    }
  }
}
.shape {
  @include left50; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 70px;
  width: 140px;
  .circle {
    @include position;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    &:after, &:before {
      content:"";
      @include position;      
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 20px;      
      width: 20px;
    }
    &:after   { left: 50px; top: 10px; }
    &:before  { left: 60px; top: 45px; }
  }
  .circle:nth-child(1) { left: -12px; top: 80px; }
  .circle:nth-child(2) {
    right: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    &:after   { left: 65px; top: 10px; }
    &:before  { display: none; }
  }
}
.caveman:nth-child(1) .shape {
  background-color: $color-red-1;
  .circle { 
    background-color: $color-red-2; 
    &:after, &:before { background-color: $color-red-2; }
  }
}
.caveman:nth-child(2) .shape {
  background-color: $color-red-2;
  .circle { background-color: $color-red-1; 
  &:after, &:before { background-color: $color-red-1; }
  }
}
.arm-right {
  @include position;
  background-color: $color-skin-1;
  border-left: 8px solid rgba($color-black, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 180px;
  left: 135px; 
  top: 80px;
  transform-origin: 30px 30px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  .club {
    @include position;
      border-bottom: 110px solid $color-wood-1;
    border-left:   10px solid transparent;
    border-right:  10px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    left: -60px;
    top: 120px;
    transform: rotate(70deg);
    width: 20px;
    &:after, &:before {
      @include position;
      content:"";
      background-color: $color-wood-1;
      border-radius: 50%;
      left: 0;
    }
    &:after   { height: 20px; width: 20px; top: -10px; }
    &:before  { height: 40px; width: 40px; left: -10px; top: 90px; }
  }
}
.leg {
  @include position;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 55px;  
  top: 200px;
  width: 10px;
  &:after {
    @include position;
    content: "";
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    left: -5px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 10px;
  }
  .foot {
    @include position;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
    height: 25px;
    left: -38px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    &:after, &:before, .fingers, .fingers:after {
      @include position;
      background-color: $color-skin-1;
      border-radius: 50%;
      bottom: 0px;
      height: 15px;
      transform-origin: bottom;
      width: 15px;
    }
    &:after         { left: -6px; content: ""; }
    &:before        { left: 8px; transform: scale(0.6); content: ""; }
    .fingers        { left: 15px; transform: scale(0.6); }
    .fingers:after  { left: 11px; content: ""; }
  }
}
.leg:nth-child(1)   { 
  background-color: $color-skin-3;
  left: 95px;
  &:after { background-color: $color-skin-3; }
  .foot   { background-color: $color-skin-3; 
    &:after { background-color: $color-skin-3;}
    &:before {display: none;}
  }
}
.leg:nth-child(2)   { 
  background-color: $color-skin-2;
  left: 115px;   
  &:after { background-color: $color-skin-2; }
  .foot   { background-color: $color-skin-2; }
}
/*/////////////////// animation */
.caveman:nth-child(1) .arm-right {
  animation: arm-anima 1.2s infinite cubic-bezier(.55,.01,.16,1.34);
}
.caveman:nth-child(2) .arm-right {
  animation: arm-anima 1.2s infinite cubic-bezier(.55,.01,.16,1.34);
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
@keyframes arm-anima {
  0%    { transform: rotate(0) }
  100%  { transform: rotate(-360deg) }
}
.caveman:nth-child(2) .head {
  animation: head-anima 1.2s infinite cubic-bezier(.55,.01,.16,1.34);
}
.caveman:nth-child(1) .head {
  animation: head-anima 1.2s infinite cubic-bezier(.55,.01,.16,1.34);
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
@keyframes head-anima {
  0%    { top: 25px; }
  42%   { top: 25px; }
  45%   { top: 50px; }
  100%  { top: 25px; }
}
.caveman:nth-child(2) .eye:after, 
.caveman:nth-child(2) .eye:before {
  animation: eye-anima 1.2s infinite cubic-bezier(.55,.01,.16,1.34);
}
.caveman:nth-child(1) .eye:after, 
.caveman:nth-child(1) .eye:before {
  animation: eye-anima 1.2s infinite cubic-bezier(.55,.01,.16,1.34);
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
@keyframes eye-anima {
  0%    { height: 5px; }
  42%   { height: 5px; }
  45%   { height: 1px; }
  100%  { height: 5px; }
}
.container {
  &:after {
    animation: shadow-anima 1.2s infinite cubic-bezier(.55,.01,.16,1.34);
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
  }
}
@keyframes shadow-anima {
  0%    { width: 350px; left: 80px; }
  25%   { width: 450px; left: 80px; }
  50%   { width: 350px; left: 80px; }
  75%   { width: 450px; left: 0px; }
  100%  { width: 350px; left: 80px; }
}
/*/////////////////////// credit ////*/
#link {
  bottom: 20px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#link p {margin: 0; margin-left: 5px;}
#link:hover {opacity: 1;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>



<div class="text"><p>503</p></div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- caveman left -->
  <div class="caveman">
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="shape">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eye"><div class="nose"></div></div>
      <div class="mouth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arm-right"><div class="club"></div></div>    
  </div>
  <!-- caveman right -->
  <div class="caveman">
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="shape">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eye"><div class="nose"></div></div>
      <div class="mouth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arm-right"><div class="club"></div></div>    
  </div>
</div>
<!-- //////////////// CREDIT //////////////// -->
<a href="https://codepen.io/SofiaSergio/" target="_blank">
  <div id="link">
    <i class="fab fa-codepen"></i>
    <p>watch other pens</p>
  </div>
</a>
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="text"><p>503</p></div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- caveman left -->
  <div class="caveman">
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="shape">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eye"><div class="nose"></div></div>
      <div class="mouth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arm-right"><div class="club"></div></div>    
  </div>
  <!-- caveman right -->
  <div class="caveman">
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="leg">
      <div class="foot"><div class="fingers"></div></div>      
    </div>
    <div class="shape">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eye"><div class="nose"></div></div>
      <div class="mouth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arm-right"><div class="club"></div></div>    
  </div>
</div>
<!-- //////////////// CREDIT //////////////// -->
<a href="https://codepen.io/SofiaSergio/" target="_blank">
  <div id="link">
    <i class="fab fa-codepen"></i>
    <p>watch other pens</p>
  </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm actually going to do is to add the code to a wordpress page. I usually create an HTML Code block, and paste the css in Custom CSS secton of my theme. However, the above code didn't work in wordpress neither. I would be very grateful if someone give me a clue how to make the code workable. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css code of the codepen is scss and you try to use it as normal css.
You may compile the scss code to normal css using a website like that: https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems you are using a CSS which needs pre-processor, like Sass or Less. Try to include a pre-processor and try again.
Try watching this:- https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I have no idea what you are talking about. Do you mean to change extension of CSS file from css to scss?

Comment: No, I didn't meant that. You must be using Codepen, so click the arrow beisde the SCSS and click on 'View Compiled CSS'. Then it'll show the CSS. Copy that and then use it outside codepen.